# When to use carte or DI server

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I'm starting with pentaho 6.
I have downloaded the trial version of EE.
I'm a little bit confused about the use of carte:
I know it is used for remote execution of jobs/transformations but I didn't find a clear explication why using carte if there is already a DI server?

Why two differents servers?

Does the DI server only allow remote execution?

And for clustering,should we create carte cluster or DI cluster?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One of the use case of Carte server that we tried out in my previous team was to use it as a DR(disaster recovery/fail over server) server. Carte servers are simple JVM instances nothing else so they are really easy to start (I am not sure whether you can have multiple DI servers.) We were running our jobs on Carte A and if it use to fails (most of the time due to JVM issue) our script use to reroute our jobs to the DR Carte instance.

Comment: can you please explain how do we integrate our carte server with the tool, I got my carte server up and running. After adding slave configuration in the transformation tab in pentaho dashboard, I tried running a job by hitting the rest api, but i get this error saying "Could not connect to repository". I am not able to figure out how my carte server would know which job to run. I have this idea that the job's information and all other database related information is stored in the kettler.properties file, but could not find a way to tell the carte server about kettle.properties.

Comment: Carte server is really a container and doesn't have any kind of routing capabilities, we had an Java based service which use to check the memory usage of various Carte servers and route the jobs accordingly. If your requirement is not complex you can simply have shell or perl script are route the jobs in round robin fashion to different Carte servers.

Comment: Hi @Explorer, i am not concerned about routing, i am facing problem with integrating a carte instance with the pentaho tool, as soon as i hit http://localhost:80801/kettle/status, i get this error on the carte server console saying "Unable to connect to repository". Now i am not sure which repository is it talking about and it even expects a username and password for that repository. I mentioned a repository.xml in slave-config.xml but that did not work.